# new Date format usage for safari

Tags: javascript, date, safari, format

I have already existing code to parse date elements from an rss feed. How do I correct this existing code to allow the date format to be converted for safari and IE?

new Date() needs converting to a format for safari and IE, how can this be reformatted to show on done? Using exact date formats yyyy-mm-dd does not render the dates from the rss feed.

```js
var months = ["JAN", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", "JUL", "AUG", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DEC"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "curl.php",
    success: function(result) {
      var res = JSON.parse(result);


      if (res.length > 0) {
        let feeds = '';
        let counter = 0;
        let newList = [];

        for (var element of res) {
          if (counter < 3) {

            newList.push(element);
            let pubDate = new Date(element["pubDate"]);

            feeds += '<div class="hm_news">' +
              '<div class="news_date">' +
              '<div class="tbl">' +
              '<div class="tbl_mid w3-text-blu">' +
              '<span class="w3-xxxlarge">' + pubDate.getDate() + '</span>' +
              '<span class="w3-xlarge w3-padding-16">' + months[pubDate.getMonth()] + '</span>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '<div class="news_content w3-left-align">' +
              '<h3 class="w3-large">' + element["title"] + '</h3>' +
              // '<p>' + element["description"].substr(0, 50) + ' ...</p>' +
              '<a  href="' + element["link"] + '"><button class="btn info w3-padding w3-border w3-border-blu w3-round-xxlarge w3-medium">READ MORE</button></a>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>';
            counter++;
          } else
            break;
        }

        localStorage.setItem('home_news_content', JSON.stringify(newList));
        $(".hm_news_wrap").html(feeds);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not against using a library to help you out.  I would recommend using [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/).  They give you a lot of options to modify and format the date and time to your heart's content.  You can also eliminate the month array.

So in your case you would do sometime similar to this.

```
let pubDate = moment(element["pubDate"]);

feeds += '<div class="hm_news">' +
              '<div class="news_date">' +
              '<div class="tbl">' +
              '<div class="tbl_mid w3-text-blu">' +
              '<span class="w3-xxxlarge">' + pubDate.format('yyyy-mm-dd') + '</span>' +
              '<span class="w3-xlarge w3-padding-16">' + pubDate.format('MMMM') + '</span>'
```